# Expected expression before ‘char’ in C

Tags: c

I must start out by saying that I am extremely new to C!

I have been through the **Questions that may already have your answer** and tried the suggestions however those do not solve the error message that I am receiving.

I am receiving an error message with the below code:

```
int autoop_check(aClient *cptr, aClient *sptr, aChannel *chptr, char *parv[])
{
    if (IsOper(cptr))
        char *parv[] = {
            "+o",
            sptr->name,
            NULL
        };
        (void)do_mode(chptr, sptr, sptr, 2, parv, 0, 0);
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
module.c:32:9: error: expected expression before ‘char’
         char *parv[] = {
         ^
```

Comment: Add braces to your if statement

Comment: this code looks pretty excessive for someone that is "extremely new to C". where is it from?

Comment: The standard requires initialisers to use constant expressions only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for an `if` statement is

```
if ( expr ) statement
```

where *`statement`* can be a single expression statement (function call, arithmetic expression, etc.), a selection statement (another `if` or a `switch` statement), an iteration statement (`for`, `while`, or `do-while` statement), or a *compound* statement, which is surrounded by `{}`.

What it *can't* be is a declaration; if you want to declare something inside of the `if` statement, it must as part of a compound statement.

So what's happening is that your code is being parsed as

```
if (IsOper(cptr))
        char *parv[] = {
            "+o",
            sptr->name,
            NULL
        };

(void)do_mode(chptr, sptr, sptr, 2, parv, 0, 0);
```

That is, that the `if` statement contains only the declaration for `parv`; unfortunately, a declaration is not allowed as a *`statement`* in this context.

To fix this, you will need to use the compound statement:

```
if (IsOper(cptr))
{
  char *parv[] = {
      "+o",
      sptr->name,
      NULL
  };

  (void)do_mode(chptr, sptr, sptr, 2, parv, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing braces for the body of the `if` statement.

```
 if (IsOper(cptr)) {
        char *parv[] = {
            "+o",
            sptr->name,
            NULL
        };
        (void)do_mode(chptr, sptr, sptr, 2, parv, 0, 0);
 }
```